# Why use NUMBER(p,s) instead of NUMBER in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I understand the significance of NUMBER(p,s) and how it differs from NUMBER, however if you know that your column is going to store decimals (let's assume you know the max but business requirements always change), why ever limit yourself to using specifying P and S?  If NUMBER is dynamic and will store the decimal places, why not use it?  Is there a performance gain by specifying P and S?  I am specifically asking for an 11g Oracle DB?

Comment: Currency? Maybe NUMBER(N,2) for a suitable value of N. Also, how is this different than for strings? Do you create your databases with VARCHAR2(4000) for all strings?

Comment: `NUMBER(p,s)` = `NUMBER` + constraint

Comment: I realize that it is a constraint, however let's say I don't care if the numbers have or do not have decimals and I am not being strict on the number of places.  Simply from a performance standpoint, does it benefit indexes or memory optimization if I use a constraint vs just NUMBER?

Comment: Check out the section "Internal Numeric Format" at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209. There is nothing said about precision or scale when storing the number so I would doubt there's any index or memory benefit using NUMBER over NUMBER(p,s). That said, the optimizer would probably make good use of NUMBER(p,s).

Comment: @halfsharkalligatorhalfman - constraint has always negative impact on performance.  `NUMBER` type is faster.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Very good input and I think the last two comments answer all my questions :)